# Best way of calling an AWS Lambda function from PHP using Amazon API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have created an AWS Lambda function, using Claudia, express and node.js
In this lambda function I have a few different endpoints, like:

```
/api/v1/something
/api/v1/somethingelse
```

I have created an API Gateway, using 'Lambda Function' as integration and I checked 'Use Lambda Proxy integration' - this is like a redirect as far as I've read from my gateway directly to the lambda function

My question is, how can I do a PHP call using the AWS Sdk to this?

My code is:

```
$client = LambdaClient::factory(array(
    'version' => "latest",
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => '****',
        'secret' => '****'
    ),
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));

$result = $client->invoke(array(
    'FunctionName' => 'My function name',
    'InvocationType' => 'RequestResponse',
));
```

If I use this, there is no way to specify the path, and I don't get any response ..

The only way is to do a curl request ... or what's the proper way ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can call a Lambda "directly" (without API gateway) but if you're trying to have a traditional REST/HTTP service then you need API gateway.  The question is how do you want to present your service?  As an HTTP service, curl is the correct answer.  As a direct to Lambda call you'll need the LambdaClient library.